# Derivation of softmax function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm reading Bishop's book on Pattern Recognition and machine learning and I wanted to reproduce a calculation for the softmax function, also known as normalized exponential. Basically, the calculation requires to get the multinomial distribution into its form as a member of the exponential family:

$$p(x|\eta) = h(x)g(\eta)\exp{\{\eta^{T}u(x)\}}$$

Starting from $\exp{\{\sum_{k=1}^{M}x_{k}\ln{\mu_{k}}\}}$ and after a few steps, we recognize that $\eta_{k}$ is given by:

$$\ln{\left[{\frac{\mu_{k}}{1-\sum_{j}^{M-1}{\mu_{j}}} }\right]} = \eta_{k}$$

then it says:

which we can solve for $\mu_{k}$ by first summing both sides over $k$ and then rearranging and back-substituting to give:

$$\mu_{k}=\frac{\exp{\{\eta_{k}\}}}{1+\sum_{j}\exp{\{\eta_{j}\}}}$$

But that's not what I get. Instead, I obtained (assuming $\sum_{k}\mu_{k}=1$)

$$\mu_{k}=\frac{\exp{\{\eta_{k}\}}}{\sum_{j}\exp{\{\eta_{j}\}}}$$

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_activation_function) seems to agree with my answer but I'd like to get a confirmation or correct the derivation I did.

Comment: Your answer is correct to me, and is the form of the "softmax" function that I have often used

Comment: It has been a while but thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was posted a long time ago but it could be useful for anyone else who is working through Bishop's book to note that both forms of the softmax function are equivalent since  \begin{equation}1+\sum_{j=1}^{M-1}\exp{\{\eta_{j}\}}={\sum_{j=1}^M\exp{\{\eta_{j}\}}}\end{equation}

Comment: It has been a while, but it is very likely that ignoring the summation limits (as you pointed out) was causing the confusion.

Comment: but, in the latter form, doesn't I need a more set of parameters to learn ( $n_M$ )? I explain better my question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365174/multi-class-logistic-regression-k-1-regressors-or-k-regressors-softmax

Answer (score 2):

As another user above has said, the crux is the following relation
$$
    \sum_{j=1}^{K} \exp(\eta_j) = \sum_{j=1}^{K-1} \exp(\eta_j) + 1,
$$
since from this equation the equality of the two stated definitions of the softmax functions follows directly.

As it is not obvious from the section in the Bishop where this relation comes from, I will provide a derivation here.

We can split up the sum
$$
    1 = \sum_{j=1}^{K} \pi_j = \sum_{j=1}^{K-1} \pi_j + \pi_K.
$$
By rearranging this we get
$$
    \pi_K = 1 - \sum_{j=1}^{K-1} \pi_j,
$$
and therefore
$$
    \eta_i =\log\left(\frac{\pi_i}{1-\sum_{j=1}^{K-1} \pi_j}\right)= \log\left(\frac{\pi_i}{\pi_K}\right).
$$
Thus,
$$
    \eta_K = \log\left(\frac{\pi_K}{\pi_K}\right) = \log(1) = 0.
$$
Finally, we split up the following sum, as we did before,
$$
    \sum_{j=1}^{K} \exp(\eta_j) = \sum_{j=1}^{K-1} \exp(\eta_j) + \exp(\eta_K),
$$
which is then nothing else as the answer above stated:
$$
    \sum_{j=1}^{K} \exp(\eta_j) = \sum_{j=1}^{K-1} \exp(\eta_j) + 1.
$$

Comment: I think this looks okay. It is not focusing on the initial question directly, but it provides a more thorough proof of the statement provided by zcahgg1, and therefore, it is a valuable answer.