# derivation of softmax

Tags: probability, machine-learning

This is the derivation of softmax in Bishop's PRML:

$$ln(\frac{u_k}{1-\sum_ju_j}) = n_k$$

"Which we can solve for $u_k$ by first summing both sides over k and then rearranging and back-substituting to give"

$$ u_k = \frac{exp(n_k)}{1+\sum_jexp(n_j)} $$

Unfortunately, I fail to grasp the process by which the second equation is derived from the first? Can someone please help point out the steps?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328115/derivation-of-softmax-function

Answer (score 0):

Exponentiate before you sum, then add $1$. Rearrange to get $\sum_k u_k$, so you can normalise the conditions $u_k\propto\exp n_k$.

Comment: I tried to follow your steps, but still got stuck: $$ln(\frac{u_k}{1-\sum_ju_j}) = n_k$$ exponentiate: $$ \frac{u_k}{1-\sum_ju_j} = e^{nk} $$ sum over k: $$ \sum_i\frac{u_k}{1-\sum_ju_j} = \sum_i e^{nk} $$ simplify: $$ \frac{1}{1-\sum_ju_j} = \sum_i e^{nk} $$ add 1? $$ 1+\frac{1}{1-\sum_ju_j} = 1+\sum_i e^{nk} $$ what am i missing? sorry for being slow lolll

Comment: You were incorrect to assume $\sum_k u_k=1$ (we'd have a division-by-$0$ error were it so). Add $1$ a step sooner.